# Multiple Zuul Gate-gateway to reduce traffic

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

Is it possible to have multiple instance of Zuul api gateway to run in a single application and manage the traffic using round-Robbin?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have multiple instances of the API Gateway but these instances should be behind an internet-facing load balancer. This load balancer would be responsible for routing requests to an appropriate instance of the API gateway (based on a round-robin or any other routing strategy).